# Swap image using jquery for mute/unmute audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I need to change the image **"icontrue,jpg"** with **"iconfalse.jpg"** when click on the img, and when I click another in this image I need to return to **icontrue.jpg**,

When icon set on "iconfalse.jpg" I require this function:

```
document.getElementById('myaudio').muted = true;
```

and when return to "icontrue.jpg" I require the reverse:

```
document.getElementById('myaudio').muted = false;
```

I try over 10 methods for build this script, search in stackoverflow and other, but nothing methods is allowed.

All methods that I build not return to original image and not unmute the audio.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: You should give us one of your scripts to help you. Have you registered a callback on the click even of the icon ?

Comment: have you tried: document.getElementById('myaudio').src = "icontrue.jpg"  ?

Comment: $('img').on({
    'click': function() {
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'icontrue.jpg')
            ? 'iconfalse.jpg'
            : 'icontrue.jpg';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
    }
});

Comment: this is for image changin, and don't work

Comment: <img src="icontrue.jpg" 
    onclick="this.src=this.src.match(/_on/)?'iconfalse.jpg':'icontrue.jpg';document.getElementById('myaudio').muted = "true"">

Comment: this work for mute and change the image, but don't work for return to icontrue.jpg and mute=false!

Comment: it's easier to set a class on <body> upon mute/unmute, and use css to show/hide/modify 2 img tags indicating the status.

Comment: I thought about it, but using jquery is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hegada/9/edit)**

Instead of images use `<span>` for your ico buttons:

```
<span data-audio="song1.ogg"></span> 
<span data-audio="song2.ogg"></span>
```

Now let's simply create our "Play / Stop" icons for our `SPAN` elements,
On SPAN click we'll than toggle the `.stop` class using jQuery

**CSS**

```
[data-audio]{
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background: url(ico-play.jpg);
}
[data-audio].stop{
    background: url(ico.stop.jpg);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $btn  = $("[data-audio]"),
    AUDIO = new Audio();

$btn.click(function() {     
    $btn.not(this).removeClass('stop');
    $(this).toggleClass('stop');    
    AUDIO.src = $(this).data().audio;
    AUDIO[ $(this).hasClass('stop') ? "play" : "pause" ]();
});
```

Comment: i thanks u for this script but i don't want this method...i want a simply show button for my background music website, and when i click the image i want to switch to 2nd image and-> mute background music,if i click the 2nd image i want to return showing 1nd image and unmute background music player...

Comment: @MarcoIngraiti than you'll have to show more code than you did. It's not clear what you need exactly. Setup a demo: jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net might be of some help.